# Unwanted vertical separation between tcolorboxes

Tags: spacing, tcolorbox

I am trying to prepare printer labels for the spine of ring binders. The text is designed to be printed on label paper sheets with A4 format, having top and bottom margins of `26.5mm` and left/right margins of `9mm`.

The format of the labels is `61mm` by `192mm`, there are `4` of them on the sheet, without any separation between them.

I use the `tcolorbox` environment as a 'frame' for the labels and  and perhaps my idea is to naive, but I just wrote four of such environments in a row with `nobeforeafter` setting for each (well, using `\tcbset` command).

Even with `\parskip` set to 0pt there is small spacing between the boxes of about 1mm, which would lead to a shift of the content consecutively, and the 4th box appears on the next page. Reducing the bottom margin is not an option, of course. I believe, that `\parskip` is of no use here anyway.

I am pretty sure, that the content of the boxes has no influence on the spacing, as long as the height is not too large, which does not seem to be the case here.

How can I reduce the space between those colorboxes to a effectively 'zero' value, resulting in no shift when printed?

**Note**

I checked the margins etc. after print out, they are correct!

Even if there might be other solution for such label printing, I would like to have some solution to reduce the spacing between the boxes (Ok, it might be a very trivial solution.)

[image]

This is the code I tried so far

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4]{article}

\usepackage[lmargin=0.9cm,rmargin=0.9cm,tmargin=26.5mm,bmargin=26.5mm,showframe=true,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
\pagestyle{empty}%

\fontsize{80}{96}\selectfont 
\tcbset{height=61mm,nobeforeafter,top=2cm}
\begin{tcolorbox}%
\textbf{\LaTeX}%
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}%
\textbf{is}%
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}%
\textbf{very}%
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}%
\textbf{sophisticated}%
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

I looked into other 'similar' questions here, none of them seems to be connected to this problem

- [Vertical alignment of "nobeforeafter" tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180520/vertical-alignment-of-nobeforeafter-tcolorbox)
- [Tcolorbox in footer with nobeforeafter adds space to other elements in footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178895/tcolorbox-in-footer-with-nobeforeafter-adds-space-to-other-elements-in-footer)
- [tcolorbox doesn't print offset correctly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178717/tcolorbox-doesnt-print-offset-correctly)
- [too much space between two environment create with tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163606/too-much-space-between-two-environment-create-with-tcolorbox)

**Note**

Here is the result with some features of the `tcolorbox` package and the solutions by Gonzalo Medina and egreg together with the comment by Thomas F. Sturm.

[image]

Comment: An extra +1 (if it would be possible) for the result ;-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Thanks, I hope, you don't mind *misusing* your fascinating package!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to cancel the natural `\lineskip`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[lmargin=0.9cm,rmargin=0.9cm,tmargin=26.5mm,bmargin=26.5mm,showframe=true,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
\pagestyle{empty}%

\fontsize{80}{96}\selectfont 
\offinterlineskip
\tcbset{height=61mm,nobeforeafter,top=2cm}
\begin{tcolorbox}%
\textbf{\LaTeX}%
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}%
\textbf{is}%
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}%
\textbf{very}%
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}%
\textbf{sophisticated}%
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the above example, `\offinterlineskip` will have effect from the point where it was issued on. To have suppress the `\lineskip` in a more controlled way, one could use the `after` key in with

```
after=\par\nointerlineskip
```

as **Thomas F. Sturm** suggested in [`his comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194427/unwanted-vertical-separation-between-tcolorboxes/194432?noredirect=1#comment449804_194432).

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I was unaware of `\offinterlineskip` and after reading about it, I wondered, if this affects the lineskip within a `tcolorbox` also. This is true, since a text spread over, say, two lines becomes too narrow. An individual `\nointerlineskip` after each box just to prevent the skip between the boxes, but not inside it, provides an error message

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You need an additional `\par` for it. Setting `after=\par\nointerlineskip` will do the trick :-)

Comment: Either add a group around this or use Thomas' suggestion: `\offinterlineskip` would go on forever while `\nointerlineskip` is “just once”.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Thanks, I will test it afterwards. For the moment I am fine with one-line-texts

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, see my comment answer to Thomas F. Sturm.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I see that Thomas has answered your question in the meantime. I'll add some comment to my answer about this.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Yes, thanks about that... I wished I could upvote twice or thrice, but... you know ;-)

Answer (score 8):

The spacing is due to `\lineskip`; the usual setting of `\parskip` is to have zero natural width, so it can add vertical space only when `\flushbottom` is set, because it has a stretch component of 1pt. In this case, you should set it to zero and also set `\lineskip` to zero, but in a group to avoid the setting going on forever.

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[lmargin=0.9cm,rmargin=0.9cm,tmargin=26.5mm,bmargin=26.5mm,showframe=true,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}

\fontsize{80}{96}\selectfont 
\tcbset{height=61mm,nobeforeafter,top=2cm}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\textbf{\LaTeX}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\textbf{is}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\textbf{very}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\textbf{sophisticated}
\end{tcolorbox}

\endgroup % the empty line is needed

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is `\lineskip` intervening? Because each line has height plus depth larger than `\baselineskip`, so the difference between “depth of the line above plus height of the line below” and `\baselineskip` is larger than `\lineskiplimit` (usually 0pt), hence TeX inserts `\lineskip` glue, thinking that the lines are too near to each other.

A different solution, from a comment by Thomas F. Sturm, is adding `after=\par\nointerlineskip` to the options to `tcolorbox`:

```
\tcbset{height=61mm,top=2cm,after=\par\nointerlineskip,before={}}
```