# Tcolorbox with horizontally separated title and subtitle

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to make a `tcolorbox` that looks roughly like this

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |          Subtitle (If the subtitle is too long, like it is here, 
TITLE       |          then it should wrap like this, and the title on the left
            |          hand side should be centered relative to the subtitle)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Here is the content of the tcolorbox.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The lines should be solid and connected, and the vertical alignment should be as described above. It should be possible to specify the distance from the left margin to the horizontal separator, and from the horizontal separator to the block of subtitle text (this will be used for all `tcolorboxes`, which may have titles of different lengths. It should be possible to independently specify the fonts used for the title and subtitle.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}
\tcbset{before upper={\setlength{\parindent}{\normalparindent}}}

\tcbuselibrary{skins,raster,breakable}
\tcbset{
    enhanced,
    frame hidden,interior hidden,
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=0pt,
    left=-0.1cm,right=-0.1cm,top=0.20cm,bottom=0.35cm,
    toptitle=0.35cm+1pt,
    bottomtitle=0.00cm+1pt,
    colframe=white,colback=white,coltitle=black,
    bottomrule=1pt,
    borderline north={1pt}{0pt}{black},
    borderline south={1pt}{0pt}{black},
    fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize,
    before skip=0.375cm+2pt,after skip=0.475cm+2pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=TITLE]
\noindent Content.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like that?

[image]

In my example code, I made a new environment `mybox` which takes `tcolorbox` options as optional argument, then the title and subtitle text as normal arguments.

The new length settings are done by

```
  my rule=1pt,
  left to separator=3cm,
  separator to subtitle=1cm,
```

where `my rule` stores the rule width and the two other options store the distances to the vertical line as you requested.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,lipsum}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,raster,breakable}

\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}
\tcbset{before upper={\setlength{\parindent}{\normalparindent}}}

\tcbset{
  my rule/.store in=\myrule,
  left to separator/.store in=\mylefttoseparator,
  separator to subtitle/.store in=\myseparatortosubtitle,
}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[3][]{%
  my rule=1pt,
  left to separator=3cm,
  separator to subtitle=1cm,
  enhanced,
  frame hidden,interior hidden,
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=\myrule,boxsep=0pt,
  left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0.35cm,bottom=0.35cm,
  toptitle=0.35cm,bottomtitle=0.35cm,
  colframe=black,colback=white,coltitle=black,
  borderline north={\myrule}{0pt}{black},
  borderline south={\myrule}{0pt}{black},
  fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize,
  before skip=0.375cm+2pt,after skip=0.475cm+2pt,
  lefttitle=\mylefttoseparator+\myrule+\myseparatortosubtitle,
  title={\raggedright\mbox{}#3},
  underlay unbroken and first={
    \node[right,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
      font=\large\bfseries,% <-- title font
      text width=\mylefttoseparator-5mm] at (title.west) {#2};
    \draw[tcbcol@frame,line width=\myrule]
      ([xshift=-\myrule,yshift=-\myrule/2]title.south west)--([xshift=\myrule,yshift=-\myrule/2]title.south east)
      ([xshift=\mylefttoseparator+\myrule/2]title.south west)--([xshift=\mylefttoseparator+\myrule/2]title.north west);
  },
  #1,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{TITLE}{SUBTITLE}
\noindent\lipsum[2]
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{TITLE}{Subtitle (If the subtitle is too long, like it is here,
     then it should wrap like this, and the title on the left
     hand side should be centered relative to the subtitle)}
\noindent\lipsum[3]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Definitely a feature to be built in for the next release ;-)

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. One more thing: is it possible to give the subtitle a more "ragged" justification, to reduce hyphenation? I can get by with manually adding a line break, but this might be nicer.

Comment: @RandyRanderson Yes, just replace `title={#3},` by `title={\raggedright #3},`.

Comment: @RandyRanderson I also edited my answer to replace `underlay` by `underlay unbroken and first`. This would be needed for a breakable box.

Comment: I have a few more questions about how to use this: (1) the middle vertical line doesn't seem to extend all the way to the margin on either side, but I would prefer that it did. How can this be changed? (2) Is `mybox` compatible with the `mycells` environment from this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250278/vertically-adjacent-tcolorboxes? (it seems to be). (3) When the subtitle argument is left empty, the vertical alignment of the boxes gets messed up. This can be fixed manually using \ for the argument, but it would be nicer to not have to do that. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @RandyRanderson (1) I don't understand this since the middle vertical line merges with the horizontal lines... (?) ... (2) Yes :-)  (3) I edited the code to insert a `\mbox{}` before the subtitle is used. Thereby, an empty subtitle should cause no problems anymore.

Comment: Regarding (1): I'm not sure why I said that, I meant the middle horizontal line. It doesn't seem to be quite as long as the top and bottom horizontal lines.

Comment: @RandyRanderson Oh yes, you are right. I corrected this now.