# No vertical spacing between TikZ Pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

I would like to have absolutely no vertical space between the two TikZ Pictures.
I could use for example `\\[-1pt]` but I don't know if 1pt is really the exact value... (so I removed it from the code)!

Where does this vertical space come from? I would like the two boxes to have contact!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength\textwidth{5cm} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=2,outer sep=0}]
    \node[draw,text width=\textwidth] {A};
\end{tikzpicture} %\\[-1pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=2,outer sep=0}]
    \node[draw,text width=\textwidth] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Two TikZ Pictures]

Comment: There is an extra vertical spacing called `\lineskip` between lines

Comment: ok, then i have to use `\\[-\lineskip]`, thx!

Comment: See also the explanations in the answers to a question of mine here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194427/unwanted-vertical-separation-between-tcolorboxes

Comment: is there a way to use `after=\par\nointerlineskip` with TikZ ?

Comment: I had to set both \lineskip=0pt and \baselineskip=0pt, or at least \baselineskip<11.2pt (the height of the tikzpicture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although using `\offinterlineskip`, as [heather suggests](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324245/), will work in some sense, turning off the interline skip for the entire document is probably not what you want:

[image: no interlineskip anywhere]

Instead, you probably want to turn it off just for this particular case. In that case, you either need to limit the scope of `\offinterlineskip` and ensure the vertical spacing comes out correctly, or use something more like a nut cracker than a sledge hammer.

In this case, `\nointerlineskip` works well, provided you note that the paragraph break between the two pictures is *required*. Without it, you'll get a compilation error. There are other ways to avoid this, but the paragraph break does no harm here and seems an easy solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength\textwidth{5cm}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=2,outer sep=0}]
  \node[draw,text width=\textwidth] {A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\nointerlineskip
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=2,outer sep=0}]
  \node[draw,text width=\textwidth] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: turning off interline skip for this case]

Comment: @heather Testing helps ;).

Comment: I only tested it with the boxes, not with other text. Oops. =)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Christian Hupfer for his comments.

You need the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength\textwidth{5cm} 
\offinterlineskip

\begin{document}
\centerline{
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=2,outer sep=0}]
    \node[draw,text width=\textwidth] {A};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=2,outer sep=0}]
    \node[draw,text width=\textwidth] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Specifically, the line `\offinterlineskip`. This gives

[image]

Hope this helps!

Thanks again to Christian Hupfer.

Comment: This will turn off the interline skip for the entire document!

Comment: Also, why are you using `\centerline`? I don't see the why at all here but, in any case, it should hardly ever be used in LaTeX and almost never in user documents, as I understand it. At least, that's what I've read.