# How to create exactly sized name labels for doorbell and letterbox?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, labels

How can I create exactly sized labels with centered text (horizontally and vertically) for my doorbell and letterbox with LaTeX? The labels need to have borders, so I can cut them after printing and the dimensions need to be exact in order to fitting into the spaces available.

Comment: To all participants: in about two weeks I'll be back from vacation AND have internet access at home, and then I'll try all suggestions and give more feedback. Yet I want to express my gratitude you all of your support and input on this matter!

Comment: Unfortunately all of the answers only give me the correct heights, but none give me the correct widths. Since I'm german, though, my documents start with `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` and I use TeXworks under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

With some more options to set but very exact width and height, if needed: 
The `width` and `height` options 'guarantee' that the width including the rulers are used, not the text area. (This depends on the chosen font size of course -- if the size is too large, the restrictions won't apply of course)

Choose the `left` etc. options at will.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{cenbox}[1][]{enhanced,
  %nobeforeafter, %only needed if more labels should be printed on a special paper with self-adhesive labels
  sharp corners,
  valign=center,
  halign=center,
  boxrule=1pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  colback=white,
  colframe=black,
  left=2pt,
  top=2pt,
  right=2pt,
  bottom=2pt,
  #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{cenbox}[width=5cm,height=2cm]
  Mr. Arthur Gumby

  Brain Specialist
\end{cenbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If some other kind of labels should be generated, please have a look on ab old question of mine: [Unwanted vertical separation between tcolorboxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194427/unwanted-vertical-separation-between-tcolorboxes)

Comment: Seems to be the better solution, but I'll have to wait for internet access in our new home first in order to installing the missing package.

Answer (score 3):

Would a simple `fbox` around a `minipage` do the job?

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}

\begin{document}
\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][2cm][c]{\dimexpr5cm-2\fboxrule}
        \centering
        My Name

        City
    \end{minipage}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May be with`\fboxsep=-\fboxrule` if it has to be  exact?

Comment: @Bernard Thanks a lot for this suggestion! I edited my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately when I print my labels like this, the widths don't match my attributes but are smaller... I'll try the other solution now.

Comment: @RBloeth: Actually, for me the labels are somewhat larger, because there is a spurious space and the width of frame is miscalculated!

Comment: @samcarter: Please try `\begin{minipage}[t][2cm][c]{\dimexpr5cm-2\fboxrule}` and add a `%` after `\fbox{%` and after `\end{minipage}` -- after that changes the width has the desired width for me!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Done. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @samcarter: The widths should match now -- I used the code and printed it (scaling disabled) -- the label dimensions are correct

Comment: @samcarter: Unfortunately all of this doesn't give me the widths I need. The heights are correct, but the widths do not fit. Might this be related with the fact that my document starts with `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`, since I use german characters?

Answer (score 3):

A plain TeX approach:

```
\vbox{\hrule 
\hbox to 55mm{\vrule\hss
\vbox to 34mm{\vss\halign{\hfil#\hfil\cr
Arthur Gumby M.D.\cr
Brain Surgeon\cr
}\vss}\hss\vrule}\hrule}
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: My brain hurts because my line was stolen ... ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it was a compliment to your originality!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but also this doesn't work for me. I get neither the height nor the width defined in your example. Possibly because I use a DIN A4 paper size?