# Insert vertical spacing after all \includegraphics

Tags: spacing, tcolorbox, vertical-spacing

I'm using tcolorbox which recommends not using float environments like figure and table inside a box, and instead suggests directly using includegrapghics and tabular combined with \captionof.

I guess one of the things a figure environment does is adding vertical spacing at the end. How can I achieve a similar thing for *all* my includegraphics? I can of course add vspace but is there a property I can set globally?

Comment: usually you also end up needing to center them and `\begin{center}\includegraphics....\end{center}` will add the needed space

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194427/unwanted-vertical-separation-between-tcolorboxes?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to add the space inside of the `tcolorbox`? If so, you can use the trim option for the `\includegraphics` command and set it globally via `\setkeys{Gin}{trim=}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx, tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

Here is a figure 
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=8cm]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\end{tcolorbox}
without vertical spacing of 2cm \\ 

\setkeys{Gin}{trim=0pt -2cm 0pt -0cm}

And a figure 
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=8cm]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-b}
\end{tcolorbox}
with vertical spacing of 2cm below \\

\end{document}
```

This can add (or subtract, depending on the sign) a vertical space (here 2cm) above or below the image. However this only adds space inside of the `tcolorbox`:

[image]