# How to control horizontal spacing between tcolorboxes?

Tags: spacing, formatting, tcolorbox, boxes, paragraphs

Similar question but for vertical spacing here: [Unwanted vertical separation between tcolorboxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194427/unwanted-vertical-separation-between-tcolorboxes)

I would like to know how to control the horizontal spacing between tcolorboxes.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{colback=blue!75!white,colframe=blue!75!black}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
    top=0mm,
    bottom=0mm,
    left=0mm,
    right=0mm,
    halign=center,
    valign=center,
    width=15mm,
    height=15mm,
    arc=0mm,
    coltext=white,
    before=,after=,
    #1
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1mm}
\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{mybox}
\bf N1
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}
\bf N2
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}
\bf N3
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}
\bf N4
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}
\bf N5
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}[after=\par]
\bf N6
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}[width=90mm]
\bf T
\end{mybox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Boxes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After each `\end{mybox}`, a space is introduced by the *end-of-line*, which can be averted with a trailing percent, as in `\end{mybox}%`.  If you wish a specified spacing between boxes, you can add `\hspace{<length>}`, but remember to end lines with `%` to avoid an inadvertant space.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{colback=blue!75!white,colframe=blue!75!black}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
    top=0mm,
    bottom=0mm,
    left=0mm,
    right=0mm,
    halign=center,
    valign=center,
    width=15mm,
    height=15mm,
    arc=0mm,
    coltext=white,
    before=,after=,
    #1
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1mm}
\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{mybox}
\bf N1
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}
\bf N2
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}
\bf N3
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}
\bf N4
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}
\bf N5
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}[after=\par]
\bf N6
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}[width=90mm]
\bf T
\end{mybox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another way is as follows, without the `%`:

```
\begin{mybox}[after=\ignorespacesafterend]
\bf N1
\end{mybox}
```

Answer (score 2):

`tcbitemize` environment is a valid alternative for these constructions. It's possible to control space between boxes and saves some typing.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{colback=blue!75!white,colframe=blue!75!black}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster width=90mm, raster columns=6, raster equal height=rows, raster column skip=0pt, raster row skip=1mm, raster height=31mm, arc=0mm, halign=center, valign=center, coltext=white]
\tcbitem N1
\tcbitem N2
\tcbitem N3
\tcbitem N4
\tcbitem N5
\tcbitem N6
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=6] T
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]